# How can I stress the GPU

Tags: c++, directx, gpu

I would like to add some diagnostic code to our application that stresses both the CPU and GPU, and then measures heat.  A third party tool is not an option.  From what I can tell, CUDA is not an option either, as it requires Nvidia's compiler - is that right?  As far as I can tell, my best option is DirectX.  Anything simple and non visual on the GPU would do.

Platform: Windows XP Embedded
DirectX 9.0C

Comment: CUDA only requires Nvidia's CUDA SDK to compile your source code - users who get your executable don't need the CUDA SDK to run it. They would, ofcourse, need an Nvidia video card and driver that supports CUDA.

Comment: I think the NVidia requirement alone makes that unacceptable for me, but if not, doesn;t Cude require compilation using nvcc command?  Or can I compile with MS VS 2005?

Comment: Yes, you compile your CUDA code with `nvcc` from the Nvidia CUDA SDK. I guess you can setup Visual Studio so that it will call `nvcc` for you but I don't know how. CUDA only works on Nvidia, it's an Nvidia-proprietary technology. As an alternative there is OpenCL, which is not tied to one vendor.

Comment: I can't switch compilers.  I'll check into OpenCL.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a shader in HLSL which contain an endless loop.

Comment: Do you have an easy sample handy?  Also, We're on DX 9.0c still.  Does your answer still apply?

Comment: Yes, Shaders are also available in DX 9

Answer (score 0):

Turn off all culling and instancing and upload tones of triangle data to the gpu for processing and drawing, this will stress both the CPU (not too much these days) and the GPU should suffer under the overdrawing burden.

one should be able to use the code for any intro tutorial for this (ones that use `DrawPrimitiveUP` will stress the CPU more, but don't require creation of GPU buffers). you probably also want vsync disabled, so that the GPU works as fast as it can(aka it doesn't wait too much/at all on other events)